# Where do we add external go dependenices so that while deploying the chaincode using fabric-java-sdk , the chaincode builder picks it up accordingly?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While deploying the chaincode using fabric-java-sdk , if the chaincode contains external dependencies peer throws the below error:

```
2019-01-11 06:10:46.220 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 2ed [mychannel][c310d352] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "chaincode/input/src/anjy/anjy.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/rs/xid" in any of:
    /opt/go/src/github.com/rs/xid (from $GOROOT)
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/rs/xid (from $GOPATH)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/rs/xid
"
error starting container
error starting container
```

The error says it was unable to find the dependencies in the $GOPATH. However my $GOPATH contains those dependencies, yet the chaincode builder is unable to pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to create a "vendor"-folder in the same path the chaincode is stored in.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0-alpha/chaincode4ade.html#managing-external-dependencies-for-chaincode-written-in-go

Suppose the chaincode is stored in below file structure:

```
../src/chaincode/chaincode.go
```

then the vendor folder goes inside the below structure: [with dependency to the files in the vendor folder]

```
./src/chaincode/vendor
```